# What is my power company referring to as the "electrical stack on pole"?

Tags: electrical

My electric company came out and took my meter. I called them today and asked why. They told me I needed to replace a wire on the stack at the pole. I asked them "what is a stack?", and the lady couldn't provide me an answer or transfer me to someone that could tell me so what is a stack on a pole where the meter is?

Comment: Most likely this is something you will have to work out with a local electrician. We *might* be able to give you a little help if you tell us where (City/State/Country) you are and what company provides your electricity.

Comment: I would believe they are talking about the point of connection at the weatherhead. In the areas I have set services this wire is the home owners responsibility starts,  but I have never heard of a power company removing an existing service to require an upgrade unless a larger main panel was installed. OR the home owner requested a disconnect for some reason, then they did require an upgraded wire size based on there current minimum standard.

Comment: They came out 2 months ago and took the meter and never told me lucky im just do renovations out at that property but I did  lose the food that was in the fridge but they told me they had to removed the meter due to a wire needing replaced at the stack and I couldnt get answer as to what the stack was so I am guessing I need to call an electrician to come out and replace this wire for me thanks for the info

Comment: spring hill florida u.s.a

Answer (score 1):

*service entrance power drop*; the point past which you're responsible for.

[image]

([source](https://structuretech1.com/tree-branches-exposed-power-lines-who-fixes-what/))

Comment: Your curved blue and curved brown lines appear to me to be pointing at the same thing. Could you please clarify that?